Helm test fails due to default service account not found
I am trying to run a test that checks that a secret is able to be created and retrieved via helm. However I am getting the following error

pods "secret-creation-and-retrieval" is forbidden: error looking
up service account deployment-namespace/default: serviceaccount "default" not found

I'm not sure why this is happening and haven't found much via searching the error online. The test yaml config is as follows
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "secret-creation-and-retrieval"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kubectl
      image: "k8s.gcr.io/hyperkube:latest"
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >
          kubectl create secret generic test-secret --from-literal=hello=world -n deployment-namespace
          kubectl describe secret test-secret -n deployment-namespace
  restartPolicy: Never

the commands used for running the deployment and test is as follows:
helm install deployment-name ./helm --create-namespace -n deployment-namespace
helm test deployment-name -n deployment-namespace

The helm install command is successful and reports no errors related to a service account. Why would this error occur when the test pod is deployed and not when the deployment itself is installed?
Hoping for some help/insight on what I am doing wrong and/or any resources on the subject.
environment:
k3s version v1.29.4+k3s1
helm version v3.15.1


The error says that the default service account is missing. Have you checked? Is it?

yes, when I enter the command kubectl get serviceaccount -n deployment-namespace the default service account is listed
